# Checking NSMutableArray for 0 elements causes a crash; why?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have declared a NSMutableArray as a singleton; when I try to check for the array count, the app crashes!  Here is the code:

```
    //  clear array that holds selected servcies
SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows *arrayOfSelectedRows = [SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows sharedArrayOfSelectedRows];
if([arrayOfSelectedRows count] > 0)
    [arrayOfSelectedRows removeAllObjects];
```

This code is the same code I have found all over SO and Google.  Using XCode5, I have checked to make sure the singleton is allocated (and it is), and there is a valid count (0) for the singleton.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for the singleton.h file:

```
@interface SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows : NSMutableArray  {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfSelectedRows;

+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows;
@end
```

Here is the code for the singleton.m file:

```
@implementation SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows  {

}

@synthesize arrayOfSelectedRows;  //  rename

//  sharedSelectedCellIndexes
+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows  {

static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedObject;
}

-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    arrayOfSelectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: What about the crash message and the stack?

Comment: This is the crash message I'm getting from BugSense:    *** -[NSArray count]: method only defined for abstract class. Define -[SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows count]!

Comment: Really?  I might not know all there is to know about objective-c, but I make do... I didn't ask for a pointer to Amazon; I asked for help.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) :

Any subclass of NSArray must override the primitive instance methods count and objectAtIndex:.

Since you are subclassing NSMutableArray you will need to override the following NSMutableArray [primitive](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) methods as well:

insertObject:atIndex:
removeObjectAtIndex:
addObject:
removeLastObject
replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:

Comment: So how do I do that?  Where do I do the override? In the singleton definition?  Can you point me to a doc with an example?

Comment: You will have to override the method in the SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows class. Here is a sample [link](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2010/05/on-type-safety-and-making-it-harder-to-write-buggy-code/) . hope it helps! but do you really need to subclass the NSMutableArray. You need a singleton of NSMutableArray , why not add it as a member in the SingletonClass and subclass NSObject instead.

Comment: I tried doing it with NSObject (all of my singletons use NSObject) but was having problems with that; however, I see that my previous question has been added to, so I'm going to check it out.  There it is recommended that I don't subclass in my singleton.  Thank you for responding; I will get back to you... :D

Answer (score 2):

Don't subclass NSMutableArray to do this. NSMutableArray is a class cluster. All of the actual array implementation is inside subclasses of NSMutableArray. If you subclass NSMutableArray then your subclass won't actually implement any array behavior unless you write it yourself.